# How to get a return value from IJavaScriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium WebDriver (.net) and have an `IJavaScriptExecutor` that I call `.ExecuteScript` on. I want it to return a value to me, but I can't seem to get it to do so.

```
string displayedCallNumber = (string) _driver.JavaScript.ExecuteScript("return $('#CallNumberSearch').val();");
```

I can use jQuery as the page that I am using has jQuery automatically. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. `$('#CallNumberSearch').val();` works when I am in the browser w/o Selenium

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

String str = js.executeScript("script");
```